# how to speed up getting coordinate location from GPS in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, gps

I am a beginner, and I am making an app that get user coordinate. I am making locationManager class like below

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation


class LocationManager: NSObject {
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    var didGetLocation: ((Coordinate?) -> Void)?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestLocation()
    }

    func getPermission() {
        // to ask permission to the user by showing an alert (the alert message is available on info.plist)
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }

    }
}




extension LocationManager : CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            manager.requestLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.first else {
            didGetLocation?(nil)
            return

        }
        let coordinate = Coordinate(location: location)
        if let didGetLocation = didGetLocation {
            didGetLocation(coordinate)

        }
    }
}

private extension Coordinate {
    init(location: CLLocation) {
        latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
        longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
    }
}
```

I just call `didGetLocation` property to get user Coordinate Location. the code above can get the coordinate data actually. but I think it takes too much time (I got the coordinate after 5 - 7  seconds).

to be honest I am new in iOS development, is that normal to get coordinate location around 5-7 seconds? can I improve this one?

I suspect because the desired accuracy I used is `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`, but if I change to `kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters`, it seems just the same

so, could I improve this one ? Because If I compare to the android, it just very fast to get coordinate location

Comment: If you use minor accuracy value you should get a valid location earlier but normally the CLLocationManager take some time to get a valid location

Comment: from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationaccuracy you can see that the best CLLocationAccuracy is kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, If you use minor accuracy value lets say `kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers` you should get a valid location earlier but normally the `CLLocationManager` take some time to get a valid location because most location manager tasks run asynchronously

**What Apple Docs say about this**

> **Declaration**

```
var desiredAccuracy: CLLocationAccuracy { get set }
```

> **Discussion**
>
> The receiver does its best to achieve the requested accuracy; however,
>   the actual accuracy is not guaranteed.
>
> You should assign a value to this property that is appropriate for
>   your usage scenario. For example, if you need the current location
>   only within a kilometer, you should specify
>   `kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer` and not
>   `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`. **Determining a location with
>   greater accuracy requires more time and more power**.
>
> When requesting high-accuracy location data, the initial event
>   delivered by the location service may not have the accuracy you
>   requested. The location service delivers the initial event as quickly
>   as possible. It then continues to determine the location with the
>   accuracy you requested and delivers additional events, as necessary,
>   when that data is available.
>
> For iOS and macOS, the default value of this property is
>   `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`. For watchOS, the default value is
>   `kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters`.
>
> This property is used only in conjunction with the standard location
>   services and is not used when monitoring significant location changes.